# Samsung internet, opera blocks redirection to Android app

Tags: android, deep-linking, opera, applinks, samsung-internet

I am implementing authentication using custom tabs in Android.
I am using intent:// protocol to launch the app since some Internet browsers doesn't support `https://`

Other major browsers do seem to redirect but not Samsung internet, Opera.

```
intent://mydomain.com/auth/callback?auth_signature=xXpD21S2fdgadf3#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.myapp.com;end
```

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data android:scheme="https" />
<data android:host="mydomain.com" />
<data android:pathPattern="/auth/callback.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

The redirection doesn't seem to open the installed app on my device rather it stays in the browser itself.

I tried replacing `android:scheme` with my custom scheme, but the result is still the same!